# Need to access URL from GET method, using C# ASP.NET Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, blazor-server-side

I've searched on here for a solution, but the remedies I've tried have failed, I think due to how old they were.

I need to access, and, if I can, parse into a list of name/value pairs, the URL generated from the GET method on a search form I'm using.  This is for a Blazor Server project in ASP.NET Core 6, using C# 10.  I'm not using JavaScript, or doing MVC, or Web API.

I saw several references, on here and online, to the "Current" value or method, and it no longer seems to exist.

If you can tell me a module and method for reading the query string I can be using, I'd appreciate it.

@page "/fetchdataSearch"

@namespace BlazorServerApp.Data

@inject DataAccessService ButtonResp

People Search

### People Search

```
<form  action="https://localhost:7190/FetchDataEdit" method="get">
```

Comment: A solution for what exactly? For reading the query string? It would really help if you'd included a piece of the code here.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to read the query string.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to include my code when I only have less than 500 characters left.

Comment: You edit your question, to update it. You only respond in comments to people to provide small clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called NavigationManager that provides "Uri" which is what I needed.